# Make custom field added to comments available in comment.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming

I added a integer list field called "field_rating" to the core comments. Now I want to use the new field directly in my comment.tpl.php with it's display settings, but I just don't know how to do that despite this should be a no-brainer. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you gotta do is add `<?php print render($content['field_rating']); ?>`